# Where can I learn?

Tags: basic

So I'm looking at Open Courseware but I'm not sure what course to look at, I'm looking for a course that will teach me how to build an embedded Linux device such as a Rpi, Beagle bone etc. (a.k.a has a display and is compatible with full OS).

Where can I learn this "higher level" component integration?

Answer (score 2):

No single course would teach that skill set.
Ability to design at that level of sophistication is like climbing several flights of stairs. You have to climb from the ground level to meet the pre-requisites to start learning at the next level.
The best recommendation would require having a good handle on your current skill sets.
Lacking that; it is probably better to draw a roadmap to acquire the skill sets needed to take on the goal you indicate.

First you would need a solid foundation in DC electronics theory.
Second AC electronics theory.
Third Solid state devices eg diode, BJT UJT FET

Really good references to read and make sure you are ready to go on are:

The Art of Electronics ISBN-13: 978-0521370950

Grob's Basic Electronics ISBN-13: 978-0073510859

This gives you a solid foundation to begin pursuing digital electronics.
Don Lancaster's TTL cookbook is a great start.
Cousera's open courseware Linear systems and Introduction to Electronics can give you useful experience at this level.
Lots of practice building circuits, (and unfortunately debugging them too) using multiplexors, demultiplexors, adders, and decoders will give you experience with combinatorial logic. This is a circuit that the outputs are dependant only on the inputs.
This sets the stage to learn about sequential logic. This is adding a new layer of sophistication to studying digital circuits because it adds memory to a circuit. So output is based on input plus what the circuits previous state was.
A really good introduction to these ideas appears in Jim Sather's Understanding the Apple II plus. This book provides a detailed description of the state machine designed by Steve Wozniak with a handful of TTL parts to make the first low cost mass produced disk drive interface for a home computer. 
Once you have made sure you have a handle on all these subjects; you are a lot closer to taking about a half dozen classes aimed at building the skill set you are aiming at.
Good luck and enjoy!

Comment: thanks for the great detailed answer unfortunately for me I have to work backwords and forwards at once! I can design a cpu in logisim etc but working into real electronics is pain staking but I'll have to make due, thank you for your great input one again

Answer (score 2):

I have recommended MIT [6002x](https://6002x.mitx.mit.edu) to many people, however as a 9th grader I don't think you have nearly enough calculus and other math background to benefit that much. You might want to go through the first part of it to get motivation for the next years of math education- you'll probably learn a few things.

I suggest waiting until 2015 before buying AoE (Art of Electronics) since the 3rd (and likely final from those particular authors) Edition (much expanded) will be available sometime next year. You can use a library or pre-owned copy until then.

Comment: Sorry, see edit. It's referred to often enough it gets an acronym. The 2nd edition is almost twice as old as you, though.